# Is Community-Bot Useless?

Tags: discussion, community

If I am right then the community bot is next to useless because it commented that [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1773615/ms-teams-chat-introduces-non-breaking-space-chr160/1773946#1773946) was unclear. I don't see how it could be any clearer? Do you?

Let's duke it out!

If the bot is wrong, please upvote my answer.

If the bot is right, upvote the bot but please leave a comment with constructive criticism / how to improve.

Comment: The bot doesn't do any automatic actions, especially it doesn't post comments.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

First posts go into a queue for review and feedback - since sometimes people react badly to feedback, such feedback is anonymous.

[image]

Now that the duking is done - and why its community that the comment is attributed to...

Lets get down to some actually useful feedback.

While I *guess* the 'skeleton' of the answer is there and arguably it is self contained - it looks like relies heavily on an external source.

I'd guess the reviewer felt so, and its a *little* unfair to blame poor ol community. You might hurt her feelings .

While copying over the *entire* post from the external source is plagiarism,  a little more detail organic to your answer wouldn't hurt. In this specific case its worth taking the advice in the spirit its given rather than take it a little *too* personally.

Comment: my answer provides precise instructions in text; i provide a link because the link provides visual, gory detail. Some humans require a visual, so that's why i linked to it. Isn't my answer sufficient without the link? If so, is the answer less cleaer bc there is a link?

Comment: I am not taking it personally at all - i thought the comment was provided by a bot and just wanted to point out that if I am correct, and my answer is correct and sufficient and good etc. then the bot is really bad if its flagging a perfectly good answer...

Comment: if that comment was from a human, putting community-bot as the source of the comment is confusing to me - wouldn't better be "community-anonymized"?

Comment: and now that community-bot comment is gone!!